# QML Wrap delegate inside Rectangle

Tags: qt, qml

How can i wrap a custom delegate i made for my listview, inside of a rectangle in order to customize the background and add corner radius to my listview items? Currently i have what is shown on the left in the image below. My goal is the listview on the right, while maintaining the current TextWrapping and whatnot seen in the current solution.

[image]

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3

Frame {
    anchors.centerIn: parent
    anchors.fill: parent

    ListView {
        implicitWidth: parent.width
        implicitHeight: parent.height
        clip: true
        spacing: 12

        model: ListModel {
            ListElement {
                description: "Wash the car this could be a really long message with some multiline support we will see how it works."
            }
            ListElement {
                description: "Fix the car"
            }
            ListElement {
                description: "Sell the car"
            }
            ListElement {
                description: "Wash the car this could be a really long message with some multiline support we will see how it works. This should word wrap quite a lot of times."
            }
            ListElement {
                description: "Fix the car"
            }
            ListElement {
                description: "Sell the car"
            }
            ListElement {
                description: "Wash the car"
            }
            ListElement {
                description: "Fix the car"
            }
            ListElement {
                description: "Sell the car"
            }
        }

        delegate: RowLayout {
            width: parent.width

            Rectangle {
                id: newsicon
                width: 16
                height: 16
                color: "steelblue"
                Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignTop
            }

            ColumnLayout {
                Layout.fillWidth: true
                spacing: 4

                TextArea {
                    selectByMouse: true
                    Layout.fillWidth: true
                    Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignTop
                    id: messageText
                    text: model.description
                    wrapMode: TextEdit.WordWrap
                    readOnly: true
                    topPadding: 0
                    bottomPadding: 0
                    background: null
                }
                Label {
                    id: dateText
                    text: "Dec 20, 2019"
                    font.italic: true
                    font.pointSize: 8
                    color: "grey"
                }
            }
        }

        ScrollBar.vertical: ScrollBar {
            active: true
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Essentially all you need to do is encapsulate your delegate's RowLayout in a Rectangle that acts as the background color:

```
        delegate: Rectangle {
        id: delegateBackground
        color:"lightgreen"
        radius: 10
        width: parent.width
        height: contentContainer.height + 20

        Item {
            id: contentContainer
            width: parent.width - 20
            height: column.height
            anchors.centerIn: delegateBackground

            RowLayout {
                width: parent.width

                Rectangle {
                    id: newsicon
                    width: 16
                    height: 16
                    color: "steelblue"
                    Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignTop
                }

                ColumnLayout {
                    id: column
                    Layout.fillWidth: true
                    spacing: 4

                    TextEdit {
                        selectByMouse: true
                        Layout.fillWidth: true
                        Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignTop
                        id: messageText
                        text: model.description
                        wrapMode: TextEdit.WordWrap
                        readOnly: true
                    }

                    Label {
                        id: dateText
                        text: "Dec 20, 2019"
                        font.italic: true
                        font.pointSize: 8
                        color: "grey"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

You'll notice that I also added an invisible Item as a container to hold the RowLayout inside the background so that there are margins around the edges as you have indicated in your graphic.

Comment: You can do the margins thing without an additional `Item`. Either with manual `x`,`y` and `width`/`height` or `anchors`.

Comment: @DFaller why are you doing parent.width-20 on the Item {} ?

Comment: that was to accomplish the margin. If the item's width is 20px less than its parent's width, and it is centered in its parent, it will leave a 10px margin gap on both sides.